# Trying to create a global variable in OCaml

Tags: tuples, global-variables, ocaml, ref

```
let generateNextAssignList (assignList : (string * bool) list) : (string * bool) list * bool = 
  let carry = ref true in
  let flag = ref true in
  let inc_bools head =
    let (var, boolean) = head in 
    if (boolean = false && !flag = true) then
      (flag := false; carry := false; (var, Bool.not boolean))
    else if (boolean = true && !flag = true) then
      (var, Bool.not boolean)
    else
      (var, boolean) in
  (List.rev (List.map inc_bools (List.rev assignList)), !carry);;

generateNextAssignList [("a", true); ("a", true); ("a", false)];;
```

I would like to have `!carry` be `false` in all cases, unless the list passed to the function is `[]`, or the bool in every tuple in the list is `true`. So far, when I use the function, it is working properly, but `!carry` is always `true`, but is updating inside the function correctly. Is there a way to make it into a global variable that would fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `!carry` is evaluated before the first element of the tuple in

```ml
List.rev (List.map inc_bools (List.rev assignList)), !carry
```

If you need to enforce the order of side-effect it is better to add an explicit `let`:

```ml
  let result = List.rev (List.map inc_bools (List.rev assignList)) in
  result, !carry
```

( Note that there is a gap between your implementation and specification: carry is true if there is a value at the left of a `false` value in `assignList`. )

But it is probably better to avoid references by splitting your algorithm in two:

- first split the reversed list up to the first false value
- compute carry according to the number of elements on the left of this first false value
- create the resulting list:

```
let generateNextAssignList assignList =
  let rec reverse_until_first_false rev = function
    | [] -> rev, []
    | (v, false) :: q -> (v,true) :: rev, q
    | (v, true) :: q -> reverse_until_first_false ((v, false) :: rev) q
  in
  let rev, rest = reverse_until_first_false [] (List.rev assignList) in
  let carry = match rest with [] -> true | _ -> false in
  let result = List.rev_append rest rev in
  result, carry
```

Comment: thank you! your implementation seems to be working except for the part you specified in your note.  To clarify, im trying to iterate through all possible permutations (of true and false) for all variables in the list (I'm thinking about it in the same way as a binary number).  So once the entire list is filled with true [111] incrementing it sets it back to [000] and changes the 'carry' value to true, to indicate that every combination has been reached.

Comment: You can fix the implementation, by making reverse_until_first_false returns the value of carry (i.e. returns true in the [] case, and false in the (v,false)::_ case.